# Get rid of necessity to repeat the name of the controller in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got the following routes:

```
  get "controller1/aaa" => "controller1#aaa"
  post "controller1/bbb" => "controller1#bbb"
  post "controller1/ccc" => "controller1#ccc"
  get "controller1/ddd" => "controller1#ddd"
```

Is there any way to get rid of necessity to repeat the name of the controller which is "controller1"? This would be nice:

```
# not valid routes
with :controller1 do
  get "aaa"
  post "bbb"
  post "ccc"
  get "ddd"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do the following:

```
get  "controller1/aaa"
post "controller1/bbb"
post "controller1/ccc"
get  "controller1/ddd"
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with

```
controller 'controller1', :path => 'controller1' do
  get "aaa"
  post "bbb"
  post "ccc"
  get "ddd"
end
```

You may also be interested in the `scope` helper

Comment: how would "scope" help me?

Comment: because you can do `scope :controller => 'controller1' do ...`

Answer (score 1):

You could use some metaprogramming magic, just because you can:

```
[
    [:get, "aaa"],
    [:post, "bbb"],
    [:post, "ccc"],
    [:get, "ddd"],
].each do |method, name|
    send(method, "controller1/#{name}" => "controller1\##{name}")
end
```

Of course, you could go as far as to write the method `with` you 'used' in your question, but this would be a bit more complex…

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `resources` to define the routes instead, that is recommended too.

If you just want to have all seven crud actions for Products Controller ie. index, show, new, create, edit, update and delete you can write as:

```
# Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
resources :products
```

If you want to add additional actions (along with 7 default actions) like short, toggle, sold etc to Products Controller, you can do something like this:

```
# Sample resource route with options:
resources :products do
  member do
    get 'short' # This will produce url like /products/[product-id]/short
    post 'toggle'
  end

  collection do
    get 'sold' # This will produce url like /products/sold
  end
end
```

You can use `only` and `except` as:

```
resources :products, only: [:index, :show] # To have only index and show action & routes
resources :products, except: [:index, :show] # To leave index and show action & routes.
```

**Edit:**
To get what you want:

```
resources :controller1, only: [] do
  collection do
    get :aaa, :ddd
    post :bbb, :ccc
  end
end
```

Comment: Would the downvoter please like to share the reason?

Comment: what does it have to do with "resources"? I don't have any of the 6 methods that "resources" create.

Comment: Ok. thanks for the comment. But it wasn't mentioned that you don't need any of the default actions. But this wasn't a wrong answer. You can do `resources :products, only: []` for not to produce the routes for the default crud then could use collection.

Comment: "resources" is meant for producing all or some of the crud operations, isn't it?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Please refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions. I have updated the answer to include who you would do it. P.S. it is not about downvote but to understand different use case of a method. :)